# MYSQL query - cross tab? Union? Join? Select? What should I be looking for?

Tags: mysql

Not sure what exactly it is I should be looking for, so I'm reaching out for help.

I have two tables that through queries I need to spit out one.  the two tables are as follows:

Transactions:

```
TransactionID   SiteID  EmployeeName
520              2      Michael
521              3      Gene
```

TransactionResponse:

```
TransactionID   PromptMessage   Response    PromptID
520             Enter Odometer     4500     14
520             Enter Vehicle ID    345     13
521             Enter Odometer     5427     14
521             Enter Vehicle ID    346     13
```

But what I need is the following, let's call it TransactionSummary:

```
TransactionID   SiteID  EmployeeName  'Odometer'  'VehicleID'
520              2      Michael         4500         345
521              3      Gene            5427         346
```

The "PromptID" column is the number version of "PromptMessage" so I could query off that if it's easier.

A good direction for what this query would be called is the least I'm hoping for.  True extra credit for working examples or even using this provided example would be awesome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a predefined number of possible `PromptID` values you can use something like the following query:

```
SELECT t.TransactionID, t.SiteID, t.EmployeeName,
       MAX(CASE WHEN PromptID = 13 THEN Response END) AS 'VehicleID',   
       MAX(CASE WHEN PromptID = 14 THEN Response END) AS 'Odometer'
FROM Transactions AS t
LEFT JOIN TransactionResponse AS tr
  ON t.TransactionID = tr.TransactionID AND t.SiteID = tr.SiteID  
GROUP BY t.TransactionID, t.SiteID, t.EmployeeName
```

The above query uses what is called *conditional aggregation*: a `CASE` expression is used within an aggregate function, so as to conditionally account for a subset of records within a group.

Comment: You're amazing!  Thank you!

Comment: @TonyC Glad I was able to help and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please mark this, or any other, answer as accepted if it helped you solve your problem.

Comment: I did change a few things: I took out "AND t.SiteID = tr.SiteID" as I don't have matching columns for that in each.  I also had other columns that I didn't mention, and added them but got an error that obviously I'm not going to understand, but adding all the columns to the GROUP BY fixed it.